# Static map from abstract class is empty in my Spring component

Tags: java, spring

I have AbstractComponent with some simple mapping. Then I have ManagerBean which is spring bean and I need AbstractComponent.myMap but it is null...

**AbstractComponent**

```
public class AbstractComponent {
   public static Map<TypeA, SomeFunctionAPI> myMap = new HashMap<>();
      static {
        myMap.put(TypeA.X, new SomeFunctionAPI(){}); //anonymous implementation depending on TypeA
        myMap.put(TypeA.F, new SomeFunctionAPI(){});
     }
```

**ManagerBean**

```
public ManagerBean {
    public void dosomething(){
        AbstractComponent.myMap; //myMap is null
    }
```

**Spring:**

```
<bean id="managerBean" class="myPckage.ManagerBean">
```

Comment: XML only, note that only ManagerBean is springBean. AbstractComponent is just an abstract class not in spring contex.

Comment: Guys I think you misunderstood my question. I dont want to inject anything and I dont want to have any dependency. Why can't I just use AbstractComponent.myMap without creating bean of type AbstractComponent, just pure Java.. ?

Comment: Not everything has to be a spring bean.. My question is why this doesnt work.

Comment: Try declaring `myMap` as `final`.

Comment: This code should work, but I think that somewhere in your code you reinitialize this variable with null.

Comment: eg04lt3r - I rebuild application and it is still null, I never put any values to this map except this static block. I will try the trick with final as Dragan said but tomorrow, today meantime I created a bean for AbstractComponent and declared init-method which initializes my map, so finally I ended up with creating a new bean which I wanted to avoid.